# Ionic 3 col-* attribute only partitions 6

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-10>
            Hello
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col-2>
            Hello
        </ion-col-2>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

As per the documentation [Grid](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#grid), It should divide my columns into 80% and 20%. However, it does the 50% 50% partition no matter what col-* attribute I pass. How can I fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
   <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col col-10>
            Hello
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-2>
            Hello
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```